# IrfanView generate HTML file from Thumbnails in cmd

Tags: html, batch-file, cmd

I try generate from IrfanView cmd interface HTML page from directory with Thumbnails, but I can't find any parameter or options, how I can do it.

I can generate Thumbnails via:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" "C:\Test\FullScreens\*.jpg" /resize=(100,100) /aspectratio /resample /convert="C:\Test\*.png
```

I can't find this in cmd:

[image]

It is possible to realize this?

Thank you, Regards, 
  Peter

Answer (score 0):

The text file **i_options.txt** in program files folder of **IrfanView** contains all options which can be used on command line. There is no option to create an HTML file. This must be done via GUI using the captured dialog.

But after creating the thumbnails for the images, it would be of course possible to create with a batch file also the HTML file using the commands **echo**, **for**, **if** and **set** with output created by several **echo** command lines redirected to the HTML file to create. Executing in a command prompt window `help echo`, `help for`, ... displays help on those internal commands of command interpreter **cmd**.

However, it would be a lot of work to create a batch file with all the parameters of the dialog. And it would make the batch file slower to really support all those parameters. A tailor-made batch file for creating the HTML file exactly like you want them would be much easier to code.

I suggest to try by yourself coding the batch file to create the HTML file. Create a new question with a link to this question, if you have somewhere a problem which you can't solve by yourself. Post in this question the batch code you have so far and the content of the HTML file created by **IrfanView** which should be instead created by the batch file.